# Spring Boot application is going up even if MySQL table is not present

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot application is going up even if MySQL table is not present. How to make sure that application kills itself if it gets table not found error?

Comment: I have understood that when spring boot start,  it checks your database connection but don't your tables. At least you invoke explicitly your tables in a configuration class for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate `validate`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

It validates the schema with your entity class, makes no changes to the database.